# Failed to Delete Multiple Collections.

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am using following code to delete **Test1** and **Test2** collections but i am getting FailedRequestException. Please Guide me to resolve this issue.

I am getting this issue only when there are more than one collection.

```
QueryManager queryManager = client.newQueryManager();
DeleteQueryDefinition queryDefinition = queryManager.newDeleteDefinition();
String[] collections = {"Test1", "Test2"};
queryDefinition.setCollections(collections);
queryManager.delete(queryDefinition);
```

**Stack Trace**

```
com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: delete failed: Bad Request. Server Message: REST-REPEATEDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Endpoint does not support repeated parameter: collection can only appear once
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.deleteSearch(OkHttpServices.java:2350)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryManagerImpl.delete(QueryManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryManagerImpl.delete(QueryManagerImpl.java:184)
    at com.test.marklogic.services.mydata.MLSample.deleteMultipleCollections(MLSample.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeleteQueryDefinition should only accept one collection.

In other words, it is a design bug in the Java API that DeleteQueryDefinition accepts multiple collections.

To delete multiple collections, you can call `queryManager.delete()` multiple times.

Hoping that helps,